# What metrics can be defined on finite power-sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

> What metrics can be defined on finite power sets?

I know that the cardinality of the symmetric difference is a metric.

Are there any others (besides the trivial metric)?

Where would one even start with trying to find more or trying to prove that there aren't any more?

I have tried searching for answers to no avail, but it would surprise me if this were an open problem.

Comment: Any metric on a finite set induces the discrete topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though we have a nice description of a power set as the set of all subsets, a finite power set, from a metric standpoint, is no different from any other finite set. There are lots of metrics we can put on finite sets, though all of them yield the same discrete topology. For instance, find an injective function $f$ from your power set $\mathcal P(A)$ to any other metric space $(X,d)$ (where the cardinality of $X$ is bigger than or equal to that of $\mathcal P(A)$). Define a new metric $\rho$ on $\mathcal P(A)$ by $\rho(x,y)=d(f(x),f(y))$ for each $x,y\in\mathcal P(A)$. This is a perfectly good metric.